# How to get one month ago from today in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I´m writing a query where i get the last month, but with the time in zeros (if today is 2013-05-21 then i want to get 2013-04-21 00:00:00.000).

So I tried:

```
select (dateadd(month,datediff(month,(0),getdate())-1,(0)));
```

But I get the first day of the previous month.

Then I tried:

```
select dateadd(month, -1, GETDATE());
```

I get the right day, but I also get the current time (2013-04-21 11:41:31.090), and I want the time in zeros.

So how should my query be in order to get something like: 2013-04-21 00:00:00.000

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In SQL Server 2008 there is the `date` data type, which has no time attached. You can thus remove the time portion quite easily simply by converting, then performing the `DateAdd`.

```
SELECT DateAdd(month, -1, Convert(date, GetDate()));
```

This will return a `date` data type. To force it to be `datetime` again, you can simply add one more `Convert`:

```
SELECT Convert(datetime, DateAdd(month, -1, Convert(date, GetDate())));
```

You may not need the explicit conversion to `datetime`, though.

Note: "One month ago from today" could be defined in many different ways. The way it works in SQL server is to return the day from the previous month that is the closest to the same day number as the current month. This means that the result of this expression when run on March 31 will be February 28. So, you may not get expected results in certain scenarios if you don't think clearly about the ramifications of this, such as if you performed the one-month calculation multiple times, expecting to get the same day in a different month (such as doing March -> February -> January).

### [See a live demo at SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/50b8f2/1)

The demo shows the values and resulting data types of each expression.

Answer (score 5):

Try like this..

```
   select Cast(Cast(dateadd(month, -1, GETDATE()) as Date) as Datetime);
```

Comment: That did the job for me. Sweet, ty.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this , it's pretty simple and worked for me -

`SELECT SUM( amount ) AS total  FROM expenses WHERE MONTH( date ) = MONTH( curdate() ) -1`

Comment: This is not good because it is not SARGable—this query can only be satisfied by running a function on *every row in the table*. That's bad for performance. You are much better off using two expressions to enclose the range and be sure that the `date` column appears on only one side of each comparison, for example, `DECLARE @today date = GetDate(); SELECT Sum(amount) FROM Expenses WHERE date >= DateAdd(month, -2, @today) AND date < DateAdd(month, -1, @today);` This can use an index on `date` if there is one.

Answer (score 1):

To get the previous month start date and end date

```
DECLARE @StartDate date;
    DECLARE @EndDate date;
    select @StartDate= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0)
    select @EndDate= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())-1, -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are many common dates you may need to pull with logic

```sql
SELECT DATEADD(dd,DATEDIFF(dd,0,GETDATE()),0)  -- Today Midnight
SELECT DATEADD(dd,DATEDIFF(dd,0,GETDATE()),-1) -- Yesterday Midnight
SELECT DATEADD(d,0,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE())-1,0))  -- First of Last Month
SELECT DATEADD(d,DATEPART(DD,GETDATE()-1),DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE())-1,0)) -- Same Day Last Month
SELECT DATEADD(d,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE()),0))   -- Last of Last Month
SELECT DATEADD(d,0,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE()),0))  -- First of this month
SELECT DATEADD(d,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE())+1,0))   -- Last of this month
SELECT DATEADD(d,0,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE())+1,0)) -- First of next month
SELECT DATEADD(d,DATEPART(DD,GETDATE()-1),DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE())+1,0))  -- Same Day Next Month
SELECT DATEADD(d,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE())+2,0))  -- Last of next month
SELECT DATEADD(d,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE())+12,0))  -- Last of prior month one year from now
SELECT DATEADD(dd,DATEDIFF(dd,0,DATEADD(DAY, 13-(@@DATEFIRST + (DATEPART(WEEKDAY,GETDATE()) %7)), GETDATE())),0)  -- Next Friday Midnight
```

Answer (score 0):

Oneliner:

```
select cast(cast(dateadd(month, -1, getdate()) as date) as datetime) as MyDate
```

Output:

> MyDate
>  2023-08-15 00:00:00.000

Explanation:

1. Use `DATEADD` to subtract 1 month from current date;
2. Use `CAST` to `DATE`, so it will remove time part;
3. Use `CAST` to `DATETIME` to get the date with zeroed time.