# postgresql : how to get previous month?

Tags: sql, postgresql

In my db, I have `date` column where the format is like `2019-04-01` or `2019-05-01` etc. If it's `2019-04-01`, I'd like to get `2019-03-01` , and when it's `2019-01-01`, I need to have `2018-12-01` as result.
I already did some researches however didn't find an exact solution for me.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get one month ago from today in SQL Server 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16675245/how-to-get-one-month-ago-from-today-in-sql-server-2008)

Comment: @ikram:  a solution for SQL Server can't be a duplicate for a PostgreSQL question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=bf42c01411b9048e0616cdb43a7cd2ad)

You can use the interval addition/subtraction:

```
SELECT 
    my_date - interval '1 month'
```

Note, that this subtraction gives out a type `timestamp`. This can be casted into a `date` of course:

```
SELECT 
    (my_date - interval '1 month')::date AS prev_month
```

---

The solution above always subtracts one month. So, if you had `2019-04-04` you would get `2019-03-04`. If you want to get the the first of previous month regardless of the current day, you can strip the day to the first of the current month before using date_trunc():

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=a85f562519e4c460c6d495ded76280d0)

```
SELECT
    date_trunc('month', my_date)
```

results in `2019-04-01` for given date `2019-04-05`, e.g. And with that result, you are able to subtract one month to get the first of the previous month:

```
SELECT 
    my_date,
    (date_trunc('month', my_date) - interval '1 month')::date as prev_month
FROM
    my_table
```

Comment: Doesn't the ANSI SQL version `my_date - interval '1' month` work too?

Comment: Yes, it does: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=e11fd4e6f95393ca6552b8c90e5d1321